# Data retrival and assignment in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am running Reactjs and mongdb.
In Reactjs, once user selects the value, I am sending that into mongob

```
addTodo(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var roomID = this.state.selectedRoomID;
         console.log(RoomID); //This value is printed correctly

        const { mongodb } = this.props;
        mongodb.db("attendance")
            .collection("MasterDB").find({"RoomID": roomID}).asArray()
            .then(MasterDB => {
                this.setState({ MasterDB }); console.log("inside"+this.state.MasterDB.length);
            });
        console.log("outside"+this.state.MasterDB.length)
```

`a)` Here first console.log is printing correctly.
`b)` when ever I do find with roomID=1 explicitly the Query method is working.
whenever I keep roomID=this.state.selectedRoomID;.
Query is not working because roomID is not getting any value.
I am not sure why it is not getting that value.
`c)` When I execute I see,
console.log(outside) is printed first and than
console.logg(inside) is printed.

As this is sequential, I am expecting the order other way.
    is there a way I can make 
sure first the lookup in mongodb happens first that is (console.log(inside) is printed first followed by 
console.log(outside)?

I see this as issue with reactjs the way I am sending the variables

Comment: I feel this issue is the way the commads are getting executed, is there a way in reactjs I can make it sequential

Comment: you may want to check that you don't have `roomID` declared as a global variable somewhere else in your file(s), even if only initialized.

Comment: Using mongodb directly inside React app is not secure. How will you hide your mongodb credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to look at the code when selectedRoomID is set to figure out why it is not getting any value.

As for the code to execute synchronously, either use Promises or Async/Await. That should help you run the code in the way you want it.

For example, in the code you posted, if you put the console log statement inside the then function, it should work fine. Or you can make the whole mongodb command a promise and wait for it to finish before proceeding further.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is the code. I can see in console RoomID getting printed from a variable it reads from state? is there anything else

Comment: I can see that the console statement has RoomID as the variable, while the one being used in the mongodb command is roomID. Those are two different variables. Do you have a global RoomID anywhere in your code? Also try printing the state variable as it is. See if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes RooMID s the field in DB. roomID is the variable which I am assinging with the value user selected that I received from state.selectedID